# Can a pinned message have inline buttons?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a bot that I am building in telegram. This bot posts a “pinned” message. I’m curious if a pinned message can have inline buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pinning a message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pinchatmessage) has a method like other Telegram bots actions.

So that's not important how you call it? With a command? with a normal button or an inline button. You should just call it in some way and then it's done :-)